# Force Root Login in Deepin

Tags: linux, login, root, deepin

Hi I have just installed **Deepin V20 Beta** I have some issue:

1. I cannot make manual login in the login screen
2. I cannot login as root from the login screen is disabled by default

Please Help Me

Comment: Hello, new user! I've never used deepin myself but these are standard things to try when you can't log in: (1) is the keyboard layout correct, as this affects special characters in your password. Try typing individual characters from your password in the username field, if they come out wrong it's probably that. (2) Switch to a virtual terminal (CTRL-ALT-F1 through CTRL-ALT-F7 until you get a terminal), if you get in there then 'passwd' allows you to change yours (3) it's possible you mistyped when setting up the password, in which case reinstall or boot from USB if you know what you're doing.

Comment: Not being allowed to login as root on the login screen is a security feature of most distributions (though most of them also allow you to turn this off). The recommended way to get root is to log in as yourself, open a terminal and then type `sudo su` and ENTER, then enter your own password when prompted.

Comment: Yes but I don't want that every time I want to do something  should use sudo su or launch an application from terminal using sudo su

Comment: In gnome is easy to allow root login by changing a specific file

Comment: but deepin uses lightdm and I am stuck on how to allow root login or just allow manual login (Manually type the username)

Comment: @Bristol you don't need `sudo su`. That's like saying "_Hello `sudo`, please can I have root access ... thank you. Now then, hello `su`. Although I'm already root please can I have root access ... thank you_". Try `sudo -s` or maybe `sudo -i` instead.

Comment: the problem is not with sudo su or sudo -s

Comment: is just I dont want to use sudo at all

Comment: I would say as a general answer, different distributions have different ideas on how they want you to login - picking a distribution that has a different idea to you on how things like login should work is a losing battle.